# Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback while using free flow library

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, message-queue, onitemclick

i am using free flow layout library in my android app
https://github.com/Comcast/FreeFlow

Here is my code for opening another activity when click on any of image:

```
  public void onDataLoaded(ParseImageHome feed, FreeFlowContainer container) {
    // Log.d(TAG, "photo: " + feed.getShots().get(0).getImage_teaser_url());
    adapter.update(feed);
    container.dataInvalidated();
    section = new Section();
    for (Object o : feed.getShots()) {
        section.getData().add(o);
    }
    container.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AbsLayoutContainer parent,
                FreeFlowItem proxy) {

            ParseImageHome  p = (ParseImageHome) (section.getData()
                    .get(proxy.itemIndex));

            String title = p.getHeadLine();
            String descri = p.getDescription();
            String link = p.getLink();
            String image = p.getImg_url();
            String date=p.getDispDate();

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("title", title);
            bundle.putString("descri", descri);
            bundle.putString("link", link);
            bundle.putString("image", image);
            bundle.putString("date", date);
            i.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    container.addScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScroll(FreeFlowContainer container) {
            Log.d(TAG, "scroll percent " + container.getScrollPercentY());
        }
    });
}
```

But when i am click on any item it shows following error

```
08-02 11:36:17.693: E/InputEventReceiver(2849): Exception dispatching input event.
08-02 11:36:17.693: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2849): Exception in MessageQueue callback:      handleReceiveCallback
08-02 11:36:17.709: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2849): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 11:36:17.709: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2849):   at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:77)
08-02 11:36:17.709: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2849):   at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3813)
08-02 11:36:17.709: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2849):   at  com.porcupyne.supergoon.HomeFragment$2.onItemClick(HomeFragment.java:178)
08-02 11:36:17.709: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2849):   at com.comcast.freeflow.core.AbsLayoutContainer.performItemClick(AbsLayoutContainer.java:125)
08-02 11:36:17.709: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2849):   at com.comcast.freeflow.core.FreeFlowContainer.performItemClick(FreeFlowContainer.java:1709)
08-02 11:36:17.709: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2849):   at com.comcast.freeflow.core.FreeFlowContainer$PerformClick.run(FreeFlowContainer.java:1721)
08-02 11:36:17.709: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2849):   at com.comcast.freeflow.core.FreeFlowContainer.touchUp(FreeFlowContainer.java:1082) 
08-02 11:36:17.709: E/MessageQueue-JNI(2849):   at com.comcast.freeflow.core.FreeFlowContainer.onTouchEvent(FreeFlowContainer.java:848)
```

but when i am printing onItemClick event on log it works fine
so please help me

Answer (score 1):

It looks like getActivity is returning null.  But since you're calling startActivity, you don't need this-  you must already be in an Activity class.  Just pass the activity directly as the first parameter of the Intent constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DribbbleFeed feed.getShots().get(proxy.ItemIndex).#getImage_teaser_url() or anyother other function defined on Shot data like  getId() setId(Integer id) etc instead of using ParseHomeFeed.